# Redux: Reuse a reducer to update multiple state properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, reducers

Perhaps it's just a missing piece of information in my Redux knowledge, but even after seaching for hours, I still have no idea how to create a reusable reducer to update many state properties.

Let's say, I create a simple component `MySwitch` providing an UI to edit boolean values. There is a related action and a reducer to update the state. I understand how to make it work for a specific property in the state. But how can I create the component (and related reducer) to work with any boolean value from the store, without creating a special reducer for each of them?

Let's say, the state looks like this:

```
{
  items: {
    house: { isBig:true, location: ... },
    car: { isMine:true, isBroken:false, ... }
  },
  books: [
    { id:1, available:true, title:... },
    { id:2, available:false, title:... }, ...
  ]
}
```

What is the correct mechanism to create various instances of `MySwitch` to view and edit any given value – like `items.house.isBig`, `items.car.isMine` or `books[1].available` – and update them with the same reducer?

I could inject the property to the component using connect, something like:

```
ASwitch = connect(state => ({
  valueToEdit: state.items.car.isMine
})(MySwitch)
```

but I have no clue how to pass it to the reducer and how to let it update the respective part of the state. I thought I could provide the path (i.e. `"items.car.isMine"`) to the action:

```
export const editBoolean = ( path, value ) => {
  return {
    type: 'BOOL_EDIT',
    payload: { path, value }
  }
}
```

and then use something like this in the reducer:

```
case 'BOOL_EDIT': {
  const { path, value } = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    [path]: value
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work, seems ES6 doesn't support variable computed properties, a property like `state["items.car.isMine"]` is created instead.

I have no idea how to go on here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have the right idea but you need to traverse down the state tree via your path in order to create a shallow copy of `nextState` with your updated node

Comment: OK, I can do it (in fact, I have already a traversing function ready as I'm using it somewhere else). I just thought there was a better mechanism in Redux to do that…

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea but your question isn't exactly specific to redux, you just need to clone your state with the updated node you wish to target via your path.

You could use something like this

```
const singlePathReducer = (state, { payload: { path, value } }) => path.reduce(({ nextState, branch = nextState }), node) => {
  if (node !== path[path.length - 1]) {
    // this was the part you were missing; you need to walk down your state tree
    // by passing a reference of the current branch to the next reduce callback
    return { nextState, branch: nextState[node] };
  }

  // mutate your nextState, this is ok
  branch[node] = value;
  return nextState;

  // don't mutate state, create a copy
}, { nextState: { ...state } });
```

If I'm not mistaken about how pass by reference works in js this should work. The full implementation would be like this (keeping your `singlePathReducer` fn separate makes it easier to unit test):

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch action.type {
    case 'BOOL_EDIT':
      return singlePathReducer(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I avoided this way as I thought there had to be a tool for this in Redux… OK, I'll try it with a path traversal… Thanks!

Comment: look at the [`immutable-js`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/) library. Really you want to abstract this way of updating the state and not deal with state in this manner.

Comment: if OP really wants computed properties redux is the last thing you should use...mobx or something is more suitable

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: this is somewhat of a Redux anti-pattern to me as it allows setting of any value in the store to any value, using a single action. Use it wisely.

`````
````
const set = require("lodash/set");
const { produce } = require("immer");

case 'BOOL_EDIT': {
  const { path, value } = action.payload;
  return produce(state, draft => {
    set(draft, path, value);
  });
}
```

editBoolean("items.car.isMine", false)
`````

Comment: Thanks, I'm neither familiar with the `produce` nor `set` methods, I have to check how they work first. Anyway, I'm trying to favoritize best practices and avoid anti-patterns, so probably I shouldn't use that. ;)

Comment: 'k, cool, but the anti-pattern I mentioned is the pattern you proposed of having an action and reducer that can modify any property in your state, not this particular implementation. You really want a separate action for modifying each of the properties in your state so your types are more like "ITEMS_CAR_ISMINE".

Comment: I understand that. I'll reconsider to create such components as dumb only and keep all the store updating on their container components. I'll have to change the app logic, but maybe it will be better, eventually. Thanks.